# C struct with dynamic array in Java with SWIG

Tags: c, arrays, struct, swig

I want to parse a byte array in native C and use the results packed in structs in Java. For wrapping the C code in Java I'm using SWIG and got everything setup in my build process.

My problem is that I can't figure out how structs with dynamic arrays can be wrapped successfully:

```
struct myData
{ 
    float floatValue;
    char boolValue;
    int *intList;
    int intListLength;
};
```

The wrapper generated with SWIG has a function `getIntList` that returns an object of type `SWIGTYPE_p_int` instead of `int[]`. Unfortunately I couldn't get my head around typemap, carrays.i, etc., nor could find any help on my specific issue. Is there a way to achieve that I can get `int[]`? If not, how can I use `SWIGTYPE_p_int` to access data in the array?

Comment: trying to search with other keywords I found the solution here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11952365/accessing-an-array-of-pointers-within-a-structure-from-java-with-swig